# List addresses associated with my wallet in a transaction

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, wallet, address

With the Bitcoin Core command line, how do I list all the addresses of a particular bitcoin transaction that belong to my own wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`listaddressgroupings`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listaddressgroupings.html) will show you all the addresses used by the wallet.